# How do you upload a file using Emscripten in C++?

Tags: c++, networking, emscripten

I'm trying to upload a file to a server. I have been successful in downloading data using Emscripten's Fetch API with a GET request, but so far have been unsuccessful with POST requests.

Here is my current implementation: (the file is being opened and read as expected, but the server is not receiving the file)

```
void uploadSucceeded(emscripten_fetch_t* fetch)
{
    printf("Successful upload of %llu bytes to %s.\n", fetch->numBytes, fetch->url);
    // The data is now available at fetch->data[0] through fetch->data[fetch->numBytes-1];
    emscripten_fetch_close(fetch); // Free data associated with the fetch.
}

void uploadFailed(emscripten_fetch_t* fetch)
{
    printf("Failed upload to %s - HTTP failure status code: %d.\n", fetch->url, fetch->status);
    emscripten_fetch_close(fetch); // Also free data on failure.
}

bool UploadFile(const std::string& url, const std::string& file_name)
{
    emscripten_fetch_attr_t attr;
    emscripten_fetch_attr_init(&attr);
    strcpy(attr.requestMethod, "POST");
    attr.attributes = EMSCRIPTEN_FETCH_LOAD_TO_MEMORY;
    attr.onsuccess  = uploadSucceeded;
    attr.onerror    = uploadFailed;

    // Set headers:
    const char* headers[] = { "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 0 };
    attr.requestHeaders = headers;
    
    // Read file data:
    std::ifstream in_file(file_name.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
    //
    in_file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    int file_size = in_file.tellg();
    //
    in_file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << in_file.rdbuf();
    //
    char *cstr = new char[buffer.str().length() + 1];
    strcpy(cstr, buffer.str().c_str());
    //
    attr.requestData = cstr;
    attr.requestDataSize = file_size;

    // Send HTTP request:
    emscripten_fetch(&attr, url.c_str());
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You get the memory leak.

Comment: Are you sure the content of the file is www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: @273K the memory leak is semi-intentional - I want to make sure the data persists throughout the duration of the http request... I will fix that after I get the functionality to work properly.

Comment: @273K I have also tied other content types, but I am currently sticking with the one which I have working on Windows and Mac specific builds. I am porting my code to WebAssembly using Emscripten, so I can't use those implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the request header has:

```
"Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=[custom-boundary]\r\n"
```

...where `[custom-boundary]` is a string of your choice.

Then in the request data, you start with that custom boundary, followed by `"\r\n"`, then you have another header, such as:

```
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myFile\" filename=\"G0000U00000R01.html\"\r\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
```

...followed by the file contents, followed by `"\r\n"` again, and finally followed by the same custom boundary as before.